# UISplitViewController as child of custom tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I've been following [this tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Tab-Bar) to create a custom tab bar controller for an iPad app as I would like to implement a vertical tab bar. However, I would like one of the tabs to present a `UISplitViewController`, whilst the others just present `UIViewControllers`. My questions are:

1) Will this be accepted by the app store? Apple's documentation currently states adding `UISplitViews` as child views is not recommended but may be implemented with certain containers. Anyone had any experience with this?

2) Here is an extract from my custom tab bar controller. If secondViewController is presenting the UISplitView, can I leave it as is? I mean, it seems to work find when I run it, but is it acceptable?

```
class CustomTabBarController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tabView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var tabButtons: [UIButton]!

    var firstViewController: UIViewController!
    var secondViewController: UISplitViewController!
    var thirdViewController: UIViewController!
    var viewControllerArray: [UIViewController]!
    var selectedTabIndex: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        firstViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstVC")
        secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! UISplitViewController
        thirdViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thirdVC")
        viewControllerArray = [firstViewController, secondViewController, thirdViewController]

        tabButtons[selectedTabIndex].isSelected = true
        didPressTab(tabButtons[selectedTabIndex])    
    }
```

3) I can't really get my head around what (if anything) needs to go in `AppDelegate`? Again seems to run fine but just wondering if its safe.

Thanks.

Comment: If it runs fine then it might be better to move it over to Code Review.

Comment: Thanks - will give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I believe Apple is simply recommending against this as potentially bad design, since they refer you to the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/). You don't always have to agree with their recommendations and very rarely will your app get rejected for design choices- the only instances off the top of my head would be mimicking the App Store or other core OS functionality.

2) If, as you say, this is working, I don't see any glaring issue.

3) Again if it's working, you may not need to do anything. But here's how Apple sets up their template for a Master-Detail app:

[image: storyboard]

If your splitViewController is set up like this and you want the same functionality as this template, here's how you should be able to get it.

First add this to the very bottom of AppDelegate.swift:

```
extension AppDelegate: UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController:UIViewController, onto primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> Bool {
        guard let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController else { return false }
        guard let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? DetailViewController else { return false }
        if topAsDetailController.detailItem == nil {
            // Return true to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Then, add this to the end of viewDidLoad in CustomTabBarController:

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}

let navigationController = secondViewController.viewControllers[secondViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = secondViewController.displayModeButtonItem

secondViewController.delegate = appDelegate
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For (3) I guess its the former! I know that if, for example, you start a Master-Detail application in Xcode it declares the split view delegate, root view controller etc in App Delegate. Since the setup is slightly different here I was curious as to whether that is needed and if so is it still declared there or somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, will have a play!